# Playing with axis ticks in a 2D plot

Tags: plotting

How can on get rid of axis ticks and mark/label any desired point? For example, in the output of  `Plot[{Exp[-x], 0.3}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]` how to get something like below (where x and y axis are marked $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (apologize for bad drawing), respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[x0];
x0 = x /. NSolve[Exp[-x] == 0.3, x, Reals][[1]];
Plot[{Exp[-x], 0.3}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {{{x0, α, .01, 
     Directive[Blue, Thick]}}, {{0.3, β}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Showing how to get the axis labels. I do not understand now what ticks you want removed from the x-axis as not clear to me looking at your drawing. If you clarify, will try to update. If you do not want any ticks at all, add `FrameTicks -> None`

```
Plot[{Exp[-x],0.3},{x,0,5},PlotRange->All,
      Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},
      FrameLabel->{{β,None},{α,None}},BaseStyle->14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]